# REST PATCH command sent by HTTPWebRequest to Oracle CRM server is throwing an Error "Unexpected Charecter (P(code 80)"

Tags: java, c#, rest, jira-rest-api, jira-rest-java-api

While using REST's PATCH command in C# HTTPWebRequest to update the data of an account on Oracle Cloud CRM, I am getting the following error:

```
StatusCode: InternalServerError  StatusDescription: Unexpected character (P (code 80)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, true, false or null)
 at [Source: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl@35aa6b08; line: 1, column: 2]JBO-29000: Unexpected exception caught: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException, msg=Unexpected character ('P' (code 80)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl@35aa6b08; line: 1, column: 2]: Unexpected character ('P' (code 80)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')
 at [Source: weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletInputStreamImpl@35aa6b08; line: 1, column: 2]
```

Payload sent is given below:

```
{"OrganizationName":"Hawaii Import Parts","PartyNumber":"xxxxx","OwnerPartyId":"xxxxxx","OrganizationDEO_Division_c":"210","OrganizationDEO_Region_c":"700","OrganizationDEO_CustomerType_c":"62","OrganizationDEO_AcctRepCode_c":"972","OrganizationDEO_AccountType_c":"A","OrganizationDEO_AccountType1_c":"xx","OrganizationDEO_Status_BillShip_c":"B","OrganizationDEO_CustomerNumber_c":"xxxx","OrganizationDEO_AssignedCSR_c":"LOO - Loop Account","OrganizationDEO_CustomerSubGroupText_c":"","OrganizationDEO_CustomerCategory_Text_c":"AM - Aftermarket","OrganizationDEO_CustomerGroup_Text_c":"APA - APA","OrganizationDEO_CustomerSubCategory_Text_c":"62 - Warehouse Distributor","PartyId":"xxxx","CreatedByModule":"HZ_WS","PrimaryAddress":[{"AddressLine1":"xxxx","AddressLine2":"","AddressLine3":"","AddressLine4":"","City":"xxxx","State":"HI","xxxx":"xxxx","Country":"xx","County":""}]}
```

The code used:

```
var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(OracleSalesCloudUrl + resource);

        req.Method = "PATCH";

        req.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(OracleSalesCloudAuth));

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(payload))
        {
           req.ContentType = "application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json";

           using (var postStream = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                postStream.Write(payload);
            }
        }

        var resp = default(HttpWebResponse);

        try
        {
            resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        }
        catch (WebException wex)
        {
            resp = wex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (resp == null)
                throw wex;
        }
```

After this step the program is throwing the error 500, Internal Server error, and the dump created is specifying the error specified at the top.

Do any others are facing the same issue?

Comment: Please format the question at least so that it would be easy to help.

Comment: How are you generating the JSON message?  JSON.Net?

Comment: I am serializing the account object using JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object) function. The object contains the data specified in the payload

Comment: Had this been working before now? I'm having the exact same issue with a code base that's been trouble free since the 11.1.11 upgrade. Then all of the sudden (for no apparent reason) this started happening. Our client is insisting it's our code, but I have no doubt there's something funky in Oracle's system.

Comment: This was resolved by Oracle. There was no problem in our code, For some apparent reason the PATCH command has stopped being recognized by Oracle. So, we  had to include the below code to fix it:

 if (reqMethod == "PATCH")
            {
                req.Method = "POST";
                req.Headers["X-HTTP-Method-Override"] = "PATCH";
            }

This fixed the issue.